# Найти TITLE и заменить или добавить если его нет вообще

Tags: php

Так нахожу и заменяю title

```
$response = preg_replace('~<title>(.*?)</title>|(?=</head>)~si', '<title>' . $row['title'] . '</title>', $response);
```

Если title нет то он создается как я и хотел.
Если title уже существует то он тоже изменяется на нужный мне + создается еще один title перед `</head>` и получается, что на странице два одинаковых тега.

Помогите исправить код так, чтобы он создавал title если его нет и исправлял любой существующий title не создавая новый title.

Если title нет - создать.
Если title есть - изменить.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам надо манипулировать DOM, то используйте соответствующие инструменты. Оставьте регулярные выражения для других задач, они не для этого используются.

Comment: Я про DOM вообще не слышал :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOM` это хорошо, но вызов-то принят:

```
// тест 1
$response = '<html><head>123</head><body></body></html>';
// тест 2
//$response = '<html><head><title></title>123</head><body></body></html>';
// тест 3
//$response = '<html><head><title>123</title>123</head><body></body></html>';

$pattern = '~(<title>.*</title>(.*</head>)|(?=</head>))~si';
$title = 'TEST TITLE';
$replace = '<title>' . $title . '</title>${2}';

$response = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $response, 1);
var_dump($response);
```

Должен работать быстрее `DOM` ;)

Comment: Здорово. Спасибо! Буду знакомиться с dom.

Comment: Из двух вариантов, работают оба, какой лучше? Разницу не понял. 1. `$response = preg_replace('~(<title>.*</title>(.*</head>)|(?=</head>))~si', '<title>' . $row['title'] . '</title>${2}', $response);`

2. `//$pattern = '~(<title>.*</title>(.*</head>)|(?=</head>))~si';
//$replace = '<title>' . $row['title'] . '</title>${2}';
//$response = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $response, 1);`

Comment: Еще бы html на лету удалить из `' . $row['title'] . '` в приведенном выше коде   :)

Comment: @MicroRu второй вариант лучше, последний, который сейчас есть в ответе

Comment: `$response = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $response, 1);` в основном все работает здорово, но иногда из-за приведенной строки появляется не известная ошибка, контент вообще не отображается. Пример takmoney.ru не получается повлиять на title, получаю ошибку :(   Мой код https://i.gyazo.com/3704126b6695869115fea8a55b00f3cb.png

Comment: `$response = preg_replace('~(<title>.*</title>(.*</head>)|(?=</head>))~si', '<title>' . $row['title'] . '</title>${2}', $response);` с этим кодом тоже ошибка, видимо что-то в коде сайта, я особой разницы с другими не увидел.